# How do I update UIButton image in custom table cell after cellforrowatindexpath?

Tags: ios, image, uitableview, uibutton, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a button in my tableview that is supposed to change after it is tapped.

In my cellforrowatindexpath, I have

```
 [cell.graphicButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeGraphic:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

which is supposed to call changeGraphic (which changes the graphic). The call is successful, but in changeGraphic the image doesn't change.

```
- (IBAction)changeGraphic:sender
{


    buttonState++;
// button state is an int, im not using BOOl because I have more than 2 images to change from, but for this question i only included 2
    if(buttonState == 2){
        buttonState = 0;
    }
    // 1 = travel time 2 =activity time 3 = total time
    if (buttonState == 0) {



         [cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"travelDistanceGraphicGreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    if (buttonState == 1) {


         [cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"activityTimeGraphicGreen.png" ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

}

When I log stuff inside the changeGraphic method, it returns fine. Am I updating the images of the UIButton correctly?

Comment: Is the image name correct?

Comment: The image names are correct, but your comment led me to explore behind the actual image. i discovered that it should be  '[cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"travelDistanceGraphicGreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];' instead of setBackgroundImage. Before, the image was being created behind the original image. thanks i guess

Comment: Wow I helped I guess!

Comment: Yup! sometimes even the simplest comments help. i also happened to create the image that i switch to to be 2 pixels wider, so i could tell that is was being created as background. lol what luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be

```
[cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"travelDistanceGraphicGreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

instead of

```
[cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"travelDistanceGraphicGreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

in my case, the image was being created as background